# Septic tank project

Tags: sensors

We are to make a project.We have to connect MQ7, buzzers and lights to Arduino. And one buzzer will make sound when gas reaches high level and another buzzer will beep when gas level is very low.. High gas amount will lead to red light glow and very low gas will lit green light.. HOW TO EXECUTE ??

Comment: Your question is too broad. This site works best with specific, rather narrow questions. What exactly is preventing you from making the project? Have you googled, how to control the components with an Arduino? There are plenty tutorials out there.

Comment: It's a good idea to plan your code by first ignoring any details about the Arduino or the sensors and make a rough list of steps you would need the Arduino to take. When you have done that, then look at each step and do the same thing again - plan that broad step into finer detail. Try doing that first, then if you feel stuck at some point, then say what you did or tried, and what part you don't understand or failed to work the way you expected it to. We're much better able to help with that kind of a question.

Comment: I suggest you take a 1 or 2 liter tupperware (i used an empty ice cream container) to test.  leave a little cup of poop and you will get all the gas you need real soon.  For your final project, though, I would have 2 sensorsper nbnoard and at least 2 boards.  PEOPLE DIE IN SEPTIC TANKS.  be safe.  UPVOTED

Answer (score 2):

Easy, this is one of the simple projects used as an introduction to Arduino programming.  You will find many versions of free code out there.  below is an example and a total newbie step-by-step.

[image]

Download Arduino IDE.  Buy an MQ7, an Arduino or NodeMCU, a breadboard, a LED and some jumper wires and you are in business.  Use [the sketch below](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/MQ-7-carbon-monoxide-sensor-circuit-with-arduino.php) or google "MQ7 arduino sketch".

```
/* MQ-7 Carbon Monoxide Sensor Circuit with Arduino */

const int AOUTpin=0;//the AOUT pin of the CO sensor goes into analog pin A0 of the arduino
const int DOUTpin=8;//the DOUT pin of the CO sensor goes into digital pin D8 of the arduino
const int ledPin=13;//the anode of the LED connects to digital pin D13 of the arduino

int limit;
int value;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);//sets the baud rate
  pinMode(DOUTpin, INPUT);//sets the pin as an input to the arduino
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);//sets the pin as an output of the arduino
}

void loop() {
  value= analogRead(AOUTpin);//reads the analaog value from the CO sensor's AOUT pin
  limit= digitalRead(DOUTpin);//reads the digital value from the CO sensor's DOUT pin
  Serial.print("CO value: ");
  Serial.println(value);//prints the CO value
  Serial.print("Limit: ");
  Serial.print(limit);//prints the limit reached as either LOW or HIGH (above or underneath)
  delay(100);
  if (limit == HIGH){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);//if limit has been reached, LED turns on as status indicator
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);//if threshold not reached, LED remains off
  }
}
```

original sketch published by [Learning About Electronics](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/)

Comment: Answers should be complete and do not link important data (like the scetch) but contain it. In some time the website you linked will be dead any your answer useless.

Comment: i uploadded the file as directed by stackexchange.  i did not link it to an external site.  SE linked it to imgur

Comment: I meant the "Use this sketch" link. If the target site goes down then the whole answer is missing most important part. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: that is precisely why i wrote `or google "MQ7 arduino sketch"` @FilipFranik  ;)